# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'content')

Tags: discord.js

the command here [ability command](https://pastebin.com/kXP4hBFd) and the [interactionCreate](https://pastebin.com/YUCQ14wi) here

i dont understand why i get this error as i have `message` defined im making slash commands using discord.js v13.6 i have some commands that will work but if having issues with this one. i have tried many things and my last attempt is posted above. thank you for time and help.

Comment: Do not post images of code. The code belongs *in* the question, properly formatted.

Answer (score 0):

You have `message` declared as second parameter in your command constructor, so, if you try to run it without the first parameter (in this case client) it's taking `message` as `client`.
I could recommend change the position of your parameters and then, you couldn't have more issue related with this.

```js
cmd.run(message, client, interaction, args); //+message
```

Or simply add `client` to your command parameters

```js
run: async ( client, message ) => { //+message
```